# Sum of particular members of an object array

Tags: c++, sum, member

This is my first question here, so hopefully it's a good one (I have searched for an answer, but not found it yet).

I have an event based disease model written in C++, and I'm trying to convert it to OOP (partly for my own learning experience). The basic class (Herd) stores numbers of susceptible, infective, and resistant animals, and the rates at which possible events occur.

```
class Herd {  
    private: 
        int S,I,R,N;  
        float birth, death, infection, recovery, movement;  
    public:  
        void calc_birth(void) { birth = r*N*(1.0-N/c); }  
        void calc_infection(void) { infection = N>0 ? beta*S*I/N : 0.0; }  
        // etc.
};
```

I then have a `vector` of herds to keep track of. Throughout this model I will need to calculate the sum of each member across all herd, after an event changes the number or category of individuals in a herd (this happens a lot). I already have 4 categories and 5 events, and this model could easily be expanded and require considerably more.

In my old, procedural code, I simply had a separate vector for each member, and it was easy to create a `sum()` function to calculate the results, but I can't see how to do this with a class without writing a separate sum function for each member (which is possible, but I doubt it's a particularly good way of doing it). I could make a static member (e.g. `sum_S`) to track the total, and update it every time an event occurs but this might not be appropriate for all members, and I'm not sure if the total might not slowly wander away from the true value when it comes to the rates.

Is there a way to write a single `sum()` function, which takes the member I want as a parameter, and returns the sum of that particular member across all the herds?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want a pattern or recipe, not a C++ `template`, so I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, using pointer-to-members.

```
float sum_for_member( std::vector< Herd > const &herds, float Herd::*member ) {
    float acc = 0;
    for ( std:vector< Herd >::const_iterator it = herds.begin();
                                             it != herds.end(); ++ it ) {
        acc += (*it).*member;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

to call it:

```
float total_recovery = sum_for_member( my_herds, & Herd::recovery );
```

If you want to use a member function `getRecovery` instead, the parameter declaration becomes `float (Herd::*member)()` and the summation becomes `acc += ((*it).*member)()`.

---

If you're not afraid to get further from OO and into generic C++ style, you can use a function template and let the Standard Library take care of the loop:

```
template< float Herd::*member >
float plus( float lhs, Herd const &rhs )
    { return lhs + rhs.*member; }

vector< Herd > h;
std::accumulate( h.begin(), h.end(), 0., plus< & Herd::recovery > );
```

Comment: That's saved me the trouble of remembering the syntax and answering! would be good to show how it's called, too: `foo = sum_for_member(herdVector, &Herd::S) // total of susceptible animals in herds`

Comment: Thanks, I've got that to work. The only thing is that I need to make the members public in order to achieve this. Should I maybe be looking into some sort of friend class to contain the function if I want to keep the members private (I'm not sure if that's really a necessity or not)?

Comment: @spaceLem You could add four static single-line functions to `Herd` that call sum_for_member for the appropriate member. e.g. `static float sum_of_S(std::vector< Herd > const & herdVector) { return sum_for_member(herdVector, &Herd::S);`

Comment: @spaceLem Make the function a `friend` of the class. In C++, unlike Java, classes shouldn't exist just to contain functions. Friend functions are similar to members and can be defined inside the `class {}` scope (this goes into the header and is implicitly `inline`). Although, if they're private, how can the external client specify which one is to be summed?

Comment: @Roddy Could do, although as the number of members might grow in the future, I'm trying to avoid have huge numbers of code replicated like that. I was hoping to at most have to define getX() for each member and use that as some sort of parameter in the summation.

Comment: @spaceLem Ah. You could use a similar pointer-to-member-function to send the getter function to the generic sum function, but the syntax gets uglier. I'd recommend against having a getter function, and make the member public.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks for pointing me in the right direction,  you've been really helpful! I'll give it a try, but might end up just making the member `public` for now if I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

The standard library header `numeric` contains the function [accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). It does not do exactly what you want, but is easily adaptable:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  int member;
};


int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> v = { {1}, {2}, {3} };

  int sum 
    = std::accumulate(begin(v), end(v), 0,
                      // lambda that sums up
                      [](const int& x, const Foo& y)
                      {return x + y.member;});
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The code uses `initializer_lists` and lambdas. If those aren't supported by your compiler, use the corresponding C++03 code (`push_back` and functors).

Comment: This does work, but members are public by default in a struct. Is there a similar idea for private members (something along the lines of calling y.getS() rather than y.S)?

Comment: This is hardly different from the boilerplate loop he presumably started with.

Comment: @spaceLem Sure, just call the member function instead of `y.member`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I agree. Wrapping the call into something accepting a range and a member pointer would certainly be better.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the initial value is also used to determine the type of the accumulator, so specifying `0` will cause it to round after each addition. Needs to be `0.`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter My example uses `int` throughout, but yes, that makes the code even more brittle.

Comment: And yes, avoiding the boilerplate code was pretty much the reason for this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up with (inside a class called `State`, which holds the simulation state including a `vector<Herd>`):

```
Class State {
    ...
    template <typename T>
        T sum(T (Herd::*getter)()) {
        T acc = (T) 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
            acc += (herds[i].*getter)();
            }
        return acc;
    ...
}
```

This works for both the numbers of individuals (`int`s) and the event rates (`float`s), and uses pointers to member functions to keep those values `private`. An example of how this is called in the code is:

```
cout << "total # of S = " << state.sum(&Herd::getS)
    "total # of I = " << state.sum(&Herd::getI)
    "total birth rate = " << state.sum(&Herd::get_birth)
    "total infection rate = " << state.sum(&Herd::get_infection)
```

etc.

Thanks very much for your help, especially to Potatoswatter. This is much better than the tedious boilerplate code I had before!